# google-colaboratory ランタイムの仕様　ハイメモリの選択

Tags: google-colaboratory

google-colaboratory
Colab Proでの質問です。

色んなサイトをみると、編集→ノートブックの設定の画面で
ランタイムの仕様→ハイメモリの項目が表示されてますが、私の画面ではその項目が表示されていません。

Colab Proに登録したらメモリはハイメモリに自動で変わっているのでしょうか。

それとも他で選択する画面があるのでしょうか。
わかる方解説お願いします

Comment: 確認するコードは[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/85379/google-colaboratoryのramがクラッシュしてしまいます)にあります。その他 GPUなどについても [こちら](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/pro.ipynb)に